# Why is there padding at the bottom of my image?

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS/HTML combo to emulate a two column layout:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="two-cols">
    <div class="left-col">
        <img src="http://stott.customer.netspace.net.au/images/aurora2.jpg" alt="Image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
.two-cols {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ibufaz/1/).

But there's an unwanted padding at the bottom of my image:

[image: Result]

Any ideas why am I getting that and how can I get rid of that?

Comment: Text has a default padding aswell... You can remove the padding by adding line-height:11px; to the div.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline` that is applied to `img` as well. Make it `bottom` and it works:

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Can you point me to a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Ok, so the `img` and `.left-col` and `.right-col` had to be vertically aligned to the bottom (in case anybody else lands here via Google or something).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. This is also a problem in html emails. Just set the image to display:block. No need for line-height.

```css
img{
  display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `line-height:0`

```
.left-col, .right-col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%; 
  line-height:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sTN9S/1/)**

but this makes `line-height:0` when you add more text in multiple line.

So I suggest you to use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:table-cell`.

```
.left-col { width: 50%; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block; line-height:0;}
.right-col { width: 50%;  display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sTN9S/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, but why am I getting that padding/space to begin width?

Comment: @AspiringAqib Best answer? More like worst answer. What if the text has multiple lines?

Comment: @Gumbo I have updated the answer for that. BTW that was given for the existing requirement at the first time. there is logic in that which makes sense

Comment: @Gumbo he gave the answer as the user wanted and still he proved that he has knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

You can type

```
img{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```